# Replace <span> tag with another <span> using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using a Skin file(`.htm`) and and transforming it with XSLT.
I have:

```
<span>Home: </span>
```

in skin file at many places throughout the document.

and I want to change all these values by XSLT with :

```
<span>Fixe: </span>
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find the solution.

Because my XSLT contains:

```
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
```

and whatever solution I found, their XSLT contains `method="xml"`.
Also I am using version 1.0.

Comment: "*whatever solution I found, their xslt contains method="xml"*" Makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As @michael.hor257k pointed out, the `<xsl:output method="..."` attribute is not relevant to the input. It merely affects - as the name implies - the output format.

On the other hand, if your *input* is HTML (like indicated by your file extension `.htm`), your question is wrongly tagged and the following answer may be useless for you.

---

So a solution to your problem - assuming your input is XML - is globally replacing all `span` nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="//span[text() = 'Home: ']">
  <span><xsl:text>Fixe: </xsl:text></span>
</xsl:template>
```